# Cannot remove AWN and desktop messed up

Tags: gnome, awn

I recently installed AWN after reading an article on OMGUbuntu. It looked very good in the pictures but I didnt like it at all. I couldent remove it and it replaced the status bar and the Applications menu. I went into the settings and told it to not begin on startup, rebooted, and logged into a destop with no menu bar, applications, and I'm limited to a few folders on my desktop and terminal. PLEASE HELP!!

Answer (score 1):

what version of Ubuntu you're using ?

I guess its having unity , then do as in your terminal

```
unity --reset
```

then give a restart .

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked a long time ago, but the answer given did not help me. I am using Ubuntu 12.4. Here is my solution, I opened Ubuntu software center, located the offensive installation, and clicked the REMOVE button. I then did a system restart and upon reboot, I am happy to report that awn was gone. Sorry I'm late but I was using windows and didn't know any better.